# Average number of skipped steps

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

We have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$ and a sequence of random variables $(s(\cdot \ ; i,k))_{i\ge 1, 0\le k\le i}$ such that, for each $i,k$, $s(\cdot \ ; i,k):\Omega \rightarrow \{j\in\mathbb{N}\mid j\ge i\}$, i.e. each random variable $s(\cdot \ ; i,k)$ takes values in the set of integers greater or equal to $i$. We can assume that $i = \mathbb{E}[s(\cdot \ ; i,0)] < \mathbb{E}[s(\cdot \ ; i,1)]<\dots < \mathbb{E}[s(\cdot \ ; i,i)] < +\infty$ for all $i$ and that all these random variables are independent from each other.

Lets take $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ defined as follows:
$$X(\omega) = \begin{cases}
n &\text{if } \exists J \text{ with } 1<J<+\infty, \ \exists (r_j)_{j=0}^J \\ &\text{ s.t. } r_0 = 0, r_1 = 1\\ &\text{ and } r_{j} = s(\omega; r_{j-1},r_{j-1}-r_{j-2}) > r_{j-1} \text{ for all } 1<j < J\\ &\text{ and } r_{J} = s(\omega; r_{J-1},r_{J-1}-r_{J-2}) = r_{J-1}=n\\[1em]
+\infty &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

An intuitive interpretation of this random variables (that is not meant to be taken too seriously) is that we are dropping a ball down an infinite descending (not uniform) ladder, whose steps are indexed by integers (starting from stair 0), and the random variable $s(\omega; i,k)$ express the index of the successive step the ball bounces to once it has hit the $i$-th step coming from the $(i-k)$-th step. Then the variable $X(\omega)$ express the index of the stair over which the ball stops.

My question are:

- Does this random variable $X$ remind you anything known?
- Do we have $\mathbb{E}[X] < +\infty$? Under which conditions?
- Can we express $\mathbb{E}[X]$ in a nice form (e.g. dependent from the averages of the $s(\omega; k,i)$s)?

Thanks!

Comment: what does parameter $k$ do?

Comment: @quester what do you mean? The role of the parameter is self-evident from the definition of $X(\omega)$.